# jQuery Datepicker year is take 1969?

Tags: jquery

hello friends this is my code to jQuery datepicker.

```
$( "#displayallformshow #describestartdate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
$( "#displayallformshow #describeenddate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
```

i set that it's return the default year is 1969.

```
$( "#displayallformshow #describeenddate" ).datepicker({ 
         dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
         defaultDate: new Date('31-10-2013') 
});
```

this code is working properly but the default year is take 1969.
i want to set default current year please help.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `defaultDate` like

```
$( "#displayallformshow #describestartdate" ).datepicker({ 
                             dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
                             defaultDate: new Date() 
                            // You can pass `Yourdate Yourmonth Youryear` here
                         });
```

See the simple Demo [**HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/QAVhP/)

Comment: it return default year is 1969 please check my query i edit question.

Comment: I have mentioned that `You can pass Yourdate Yourmonth Youryear here`

Comment: ok sorry i pass date,month,year and thank you so much dear gautam.

Comment: new Date('31-10-2013') i set that but this is not working how to write default date into Date() function please help.

Answer (score 1):

Try [setDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-setDate)

```
$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate", new Date());
```

Also read [defaultDate](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-defaultDate)

Update Try

```
$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate", "31/10/2013");
```

Comment: $( "#displayallformshow #describeenddate" ).datepicker("setDate", new Date());  i set then after the datepicker is not display or any error is not display in consol.

Comment: @renishkhunt Try `$("#mydate").datepicker("setDate", "31/10/2013");
`

Comment: hello tushar this is not working this give above problem datepicker is not show or any error or but is not show into console. thank you dear.